# Struggling with a mobile slide menu in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a simple mobile sliding menu using jquery and CSS transitions. Below is a jsfiddle link showing it.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari (8.0.6) the fixed menu (the a href element with a class of ".menu-toggle", doesn't slide right with the body, even though it's within the body container.

https://jsfiddle.net/3byd8ntt/3/

**The HTML**

```
<body class="menu">
```

```
<nav class="menu-slide" id="sliding-menu">
    <ul class="mobile-list">
        <li><a href="#pg1">One</a>

        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#pg2">Two</a>

        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#pg3">Three</a>

        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#pg4">Four</a>

        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#pg5">Five</a>

        </li>
        <hr>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**The CSS**

```
.menu-toggle {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color: #333;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.menu {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.menu-open {
    left: 231px;
}

.menu-open .menu-slide {
    left:0;
}

.menu-slide,
.menu {
    -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.menu-slide {
    background-color:#333;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -231px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;

}

.mobile-list {
    color:black;
}

.mobile-list li {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mobile-list a {
    color: black;

}


#sliding-menu {
    background-color: #fff;


}

.menu-toggle img{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:  #333;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    color: white;
    width: 45px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.menu-toggle p{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
.menu-toggle:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu toggle:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.menu toggle:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.ico-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
```

Here is the webpage I'm actually using it on, if you open it in safari you'll see what I mean. Resize browser to show mobile layout.

http://theomjones.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get `.menu-toggle` to slide in safari if I change it's style from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`.

It appears to work on your website without breaking anything.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I was able to get the same results as above and maintain the fixed nature of the nav bar. You need to add the one line with `$('.menu-toggle')` to the JS and add `.menu-toggle` to the CSS transition style. This fiddle shows the working code https://jsfiddle.net/3byd8ntt/5/

JS

```
(function () {
    var body = $('body');
    $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function () {
        body.toggleClass('menu-open');
        $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-open')
        return false;
    });
})();
```

CSS

```
.menu-slide,
.menu,
.menu-toggle {
    -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Comment: This does work, but it means compromising on the fixed navbar, which I'd prefer to have. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @senojoeht Ah sorry about that, I was able to get the same behavior and maintain the fixed nature of the nav bar. Check my edit above.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution. Mobile safari doesn't repaint the canvas until after scrolling has stopped. This causes fixed elements (depending on how they're used) to pop into view and then disappear once scrolling has stopped.

You should use ios simulator that comes with xcode instead of resizing your browser window as there are differences between mobile and desktop browsers